# Convert Stored Proc to use Date CTE instead of single date

Tags: sql-server, date

I have an existing stored procedure that i use to get available bookings for my database system.  I currently pass in as a property the current date to display all bookings for a specific day.  What i would like to do is pass in a date range (using a CTE) as the "date" part of the query so i can get all the bookings in a complete range rather than a single day only.

Below is my existing Stored Proc:  As you can see below i use the @CurrentDay property within my select statement (and sub queries).  How can i use the CTE (at bottom of post) and essentially "for each" it instead of using the currently passed in date?

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUpcomingTrialSlots] 
                @LocationId int, 
                @CurrentDateTime datetime
            AS
            BEGIN


            declare @CurrentDay Date

            declare @WindowTimeStart DateTime

            set datefirst 1
            select @CurrentDay = CONVERT(date, @CurrentDateTime)
            select @WindowTimeStart = CONVERT(time,@CurrentDateTime)

            -- Day One
            SELECT * FROM
            (
            select  ts.id TimeSlotId,
                    @locationId LocationId,
                    @CurrentDay BookingDay,
                    datename(dw,DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDay)-1) DayOfWeek,
                    ts.StartTime,
                    COALESCE(
                        (select top 1 AvailableSlots 
                              FROM TrialTimeBlockOverride
                              where CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.EndTime AS DATETIME)) 
                              between 
                              CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideStartDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltOpenTime AS DATETIME)) 
                              and 
                              CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideEndDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltCloseTime AS DATETIME))     
                              and
                              LocationId = @LocationId          
                        )
                    , 
                        (select top 1 AvailableSlots from TrialTimeBlock where DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDay) 
                                and ts.StartTime >= starttime and ts.StartTime < endtime and LocationId = @LocationId)              
                    ) as AvailableSlots,
                    ts.EndTime,
                case   
                    when
                        EXISTS (select * from TrialTimeBlock where ts.StartTime >= StartTime and ts.StartTime < EndTime and LocationId = @LocationId  and DayOfWeek = datepart(dw, @CurrentDay)) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                    else CAST(0 AS BIT)
                end as TrialSlot,
                case   
                    when
                        EXISTS (
                        SELECT *
                          FROM TrialTimeBlockOverride
                          where CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME)) 
                          >= 
                          CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideStartDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltOpenTime AS DATETIME)) 
                          and
                          CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME)) 
                          <
                          CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideEndDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltCloseTime AS DATETIME))     
                          and
                          LocationId = @LocationId  
                          and 
                          AvailableSlots = 0
                        ) THEN 0  /*This doesn't seem right to me */
                    else 1
                end as [TrialTimeAvailable],
                case   
                    when
                        EXISTS (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM OpeningHourOverride
                        where CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME)) 
                        >= 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideStartDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltOpenTime AS DATETIME))            
                        and 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME))
                        < 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideEndDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltCloseTime AS DATETIME))     
                        and
                        LocationId = @LocationId  
                        and 
                        AvailableSlots = 0
                        ) THEN 'Closed'  /*This doesn't seem right to me */
                    else 'Open'
                end as [OpenStatus],
                case   
                    when
                        (select count(*) from InitialAssessment where LocationId = @LocationId and TimeSlotId = ts.Id and AssessmentDate = @CurrentDay) > 1 THEN 'true'
                    else 'false'
                end as HasAssessment,
                (select count(*) from InitialAssessment where LocationId = @LocationId and TimeSlotId = ts.Id and AssessmentDate = @CurrentDay and IsFriendRecommendation is null) as AssessmentCount,
                case
                    when
                        EXISTS (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM OpeningHourOverride
                        where CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME)) 
                        >= 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideStartDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltOpenTime AS DATETIME))            
                        and 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME))
                        < 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideEndDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltCloseTime AS DATETIME))     
                        and
                        LocationId = @LocationId  
                        ) THEN 
                        (SELECT OverrideReason
                        FROM OpeningHourOverride
                        where CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME)) 
                        >= 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideStartDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltOpenTime AS DATETIME))            
                        and 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@CurrentDay AS DATETIME) + CAST(ts.StartTime AS DATETIME))
                        < 
                        CONVERT(datetime, CAST(OverrideEndDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(AltCloseTime AS DATETIME))     
                        and
                        LocationId = @LocationId)

                          /*This doesn't seem right to me */
                    else ''
                end as ClosureReason

            from    Timeslot ts
            left join   OpeningHour oh
                on  @locationId = oh.LocationId 
                and oh.DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, @CurrentDay)
            where   ts.StartTime >= oh.OpenTime 
            and     ts.EndTime < oh.CloseTime
            and     datepart(minute,ts.StartTime) = 0
            and     CAST(ts.StartTime as DateTime) > @WindowTimeStart 

            ) T WHERE TrialSlot = 1
            AND AssessmentCount <AvailableSlots
            And OpenStatus = 'Open'
            AND TrialTimeAvailable = 1
            order by 
            BookingDay,
            StartTime


            END
```

CTE example SQL

```
 declare @StartDate date = '2017-01-01'
declare @EndDate date = '2017-01-10'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS TrialDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,TrialDate) as currentDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,TrialDate) <=  @EndDate
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two quick options:

**Option 1 - Ad-hoc Tally Table**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-01-10'
Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),@Date1) From  master..spt_values
```

**Returns**

```
D
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-07
2017-01-08
2017-01-09
2017-01-10
```

**Option 2: Table-Valued-Function**

Offers a few more options: User supplied Date/Time Range, DatePart and Increment, and is faster that the CTE.  Also easy to incorporate into a sub-query and/or CROSS APPLY.

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-01-10'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](@Date1,@Date2,'DD',1)
```

Returns

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
2       2017-01-02 00:00:00.000
3       2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
4       2017-01-04 00:00:00.000
5       2017-01-05 00:00:00.000
6       2017-01-06 00:00:00.000
7       2017-01-07 00:00:00.000
8       2017-01-08 00:00:00.000
9       2017-01-09 00:00:00.000
10      2017-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for this...sorry if am wasn't being 100% clear..  I can create the CTE no problems, the problem is how do i take that CTE and apply it to my query that uses currently only a single date?

Comment: @ChristopherPettigrew are you looking to run your stored procedure N times?  If so, convert it into a TVF and call it via a CROSS APPLY

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can convert your stored procedure to a TVF

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2017-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-01-10'
Declare @LocationId int = 1

Select A.D  -- << Optional
      ,B.*
 From (Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),@Date1) From  master..spt_values) A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select * 
                From [dbo].[tvf_GetUpcomingTrialSlots](@LocationId,A.D) 
                Order By BookingDay,StartTime    
             ) B
```